# How to blit a new background image after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have a background image currently in the game and I would like to change the image after 30 seconds. What would be the best way to do this, a function? A loop? or a pygame function such as the pygame wait function?

```
def main():
    #Loading the music for the title screen of the game and playing it infintely.
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\\Users\\Joseph Molina\\Desktop\\CST\\KeyGen.ogg')
    sound.play(loops = -1)

    while True:

        global total_frames
        process(bug,FPS, total_frames, SCREENHEIGHT)

        #LOGIC
        bug.motion(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
        Enemy.movement(SCREENWIDTH)
        BugProjectile.movement()
        total_frames += 1


    #Bliting the image of the background into the screen at the given coordinates
        screen.blit(backgroundImg, (0,0))

        #Draws all the sprites to the screen
        BaseClass.allsprites.draw(screen)
        i = 0
        if i < 255:
            i += 5
        if i > 255:    
            secondImg = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Joseph Molina\\Desktop\\CST\\anything.jpg')
            screen.blit(secondImg, (0,0))


              #pygame.tick(1000)



        #Makes sure that everything is being drawn on the screen
        pygame.display.flip()
        #How many frames are going to be in a second
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an event using [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer):

> **pygame.time.set_timer()**

*repeatedly create an event on the event queue*

> 

`set_timer(eventid, milliseconds) -> None`

> Set an event type to appear on the event queue every given number of milliseconds. The first event will not appear until the amount of time has passed.
>
> Every event type can have a separate timer attached to it. It is best to use the value between pygame.USEREVENT and pygame.NUMEVENTS.
>
> To disable the timer for an event, set the milliseconds argument to 0.

and when the event occurs, just change `backgroundImg` to another `Surface`.

```
def main():
    CHANGEEVENT = pygame.USEREVENT+1
    pygame.time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT, 30000)

    #Loading the music for the title screen of the game and playing it infintely.
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\\Users\\Joseph Molina\\Desktop\\CST\\KeyGen.ogg')
    sound.play(loops = -1)

    while True:
        if pygame.event.get(CHANGEEVENT ):
            backgroundImg = get_another_image()
        ...
```

Comment: so for the get_another_image() function. I would have to load in the new image and also blit it?

Comment: Since you blit the `Surface` in the `backgorundImg` variable to the screen later in your code, just have `get_another_image` return a new `Surface`. Note that you don't have to reload the images every time from disk. Just cache them in a list or dict or something.